# how to calculate statistical significance using WEKA Java API?

Tags: java, machine-learning, statistics, weka

I'm attempting to calculate the statistical significance of classifiers using WEKA Java API. I was reading the documentation and see that I need to use `calculateStatistics` from `PairedCorrectedTTester` I'm not sure how to use it.

Any ideas?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ZeroR zr = new ZeroR();
        Bagging bg = new Bagging();

        Experiment exp = new Experiment();
        exp.setPropertyArray(new Classifier[0]);
        exp.setUsePropertyIterator(true);

        SplitEvaluator se = null;
        Classifier sec = null;

        se = new ClassifierSplitEvaluator();
        sec = ((ClassifierSplitEvaluator) se).getClassifier();

        CrossValidationResultProducer cvrp = new CrossValidationResultProducer();
        cvrp.setNumFolds(10);
        cvrp.setSplitEvaluator(se);

        PropertyNode[] propertyPath = new PropertyNode[2];
        propertyPath[0] = new PropertyNode(
                se,
                new PropertyDescriptor("splitEvaluator", CrossValidationResultProducer.class), CrossValidationResultProducer.class
        );

        propertyPath[1] = new PropertyNode(
                sec,
                new PropertyDescriptor("classifier",
                        se.getClass()),
                se.getClass()
        );

        exp.setResultProducer(cvrp);
        exp.setPropertyPath(propertyPath);

        // set classifiers here
        exp.setPropertyArray(new Classifier[]{zr, bg});

        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        File file = new File("dataset arff file");

        model.addElement(file);

        exp.setDatasets(model);

        InstancesResultListener irl = new InstancesResultListener();

        irl.setOutputFile(new File("output.csv"));
        exp.setResultListener(irl);

        exp.initialize();
        exp.runExperiment();
        exp.postProcess();

        PairedCorrectedTTester tester = new PairedCorrectedTTester();
        Instances result = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(irl.getOutputFile())));

        tester.setInstances(result);
        tester.setSortColumn(-1);

        tester.setRunColumn(result.attribute("Key_Run").index());
        tester.setFoldColumn(result.attribute("Key_Fold").index());
        tester.setResultsetKeyColumns(
                new Range(
                        ""
                                + (result.attribute("Key_Dataset").index() + 1)));
        tester.setDatasetKeyColumns(
                new Range(
                        ""
                                + (result.attribute("Key_Scheme").index() + 1)
                                + ","
                                + (result.attribute("Key_Scheme_options").index() + 1)
                                + ","
                                + (result.attribute("Key_Scheme_version_ID").index() + 1)));
        tester.setResultMatrix(new ResultMatrixPlainText());
        tester.setDisplayedResultsets(null);
        tester.setSignificanceLevel(0.05);
        tester.setShowStdDevs(true);

        tester.multiResultsetFull(0, result.attribute("Percent_correct").index());
        System.out.println("\nResult:");

        ResultMatrix matrix = tester.getResultMatrix();

        System.out.println(matrix.toStringMatrix());
}
```

Results from code above:
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgbqU.png)

What I want is similar to the WEKA GUI (circled in red):

[Statistical Significance using WEKA GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W58qm.png)

Resources Used:

- https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/experimenter/using_the_experiment_api/
- [http://sce.carleton.ca/~mehrfard/repository/Case_Studies_(No_instrumentation)/Weka/doc/weka/experiment/PairedCorrectedTTester.html](http://sce.carleton.ca/%7Emehrfard/repository/Case_Studies_(No_instrumentation)/Weka/doc/weka/experiment/PairedCorrectedTTester.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to swap the **key columns** for **dataset** and **resultset** if you want to statistically evaluate classifiers on datasets (rather than datasets on classifiers):

```java
    tester.setDatasetKeyColumns(
    new Range(
        ""
        + (result.attribute("Key_Dataset").index() + 1)));
    tester.setResultsetKeyColumns(
    new Range(
        ""
        + (result.attribute("Key_Scheme").index() + 1)
        + ","
        + (result.attribute("Key_Scheme_options").index() + 1)
        + ","
        + (result.attribute("Key_Scheme_version_ID").index() + 1)));
```

That will give you something like this when using the UCI dataset anneal:

```
Result:
Dataset                   (1) rules.ZeroR '' | (2) meta.Baggin
--------------------------------------------------------------
anneal                   (100)   76.17(0.55) |   98.73(1.12) v
--------------------------------------------------------------
                                     (v/ /*) |         (1/0/0)
```